# How to create Job Schedule for every hour?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, job-scheduling

I've already tried to implement this using the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) and [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler), but it's not allowing me to kill the app from the background.

Comment: When app is force stopped jobs will be stopped and no longer work.

Comment: Use a foreground service to do that!!

Comment: Please provide code snippets from what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using WorkerManager.

1) Include it from gradle

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
```

2) Inherit abstract class Worker, implement "doWork" method and put your logic into this method.

```
class MyWorker(val ctx : Context, params : WorkerParameters) : Worker(ctx, params)
{
    override fun doWork(): Result
    {
        //put your work here
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

3) Create WorkManager, for example, in your ViewModel:

```
private val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
```

4) Start your periodic work in the background:

```
workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "workName",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                PeriodicWorkRequest
                        .Builder(MyWorker::class.java, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build())
```

For more info download official example:

```
git clone -b codelab_start_kt https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager
```

Or follow this awesome codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/index.html#0

Comment: `PeriodicWorkRequest` requires a minimum of 15 minutes to start!

Answer (score 0):

as @Niladree said you can use **WorkManager** which is part of the jetpack. but if the **exact time** of the job is important you must use an ***alarm manager*** with a ***broadcast receiver***, because the work manager will do the job in the time if it's an appropriate time to execute as of memory or CPU and it may cause a delay to perform in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the latest WorkManager library which have a periodic functionality.

Add the dependency as follows:

```
// (Java only)
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0'

// Kotlin + coroutines
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'
```

And then you can create a periodic request like this:

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiresCharging(true)
    .build()

val saveRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<SaveImageToFileWorker>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .setConstraints(constraints)
    .build()

 WorkManager.getInstance(myContext).enqueue(saveRequest)
```

For detailed info see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Comment: When app is force stopped, the work will not get triggered, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116677275

Comment: This issue is fixed. Please check the status of the issue on the right side panel.